# Unexpected EOF error

Tags: linux, unix, scripting

Script for yourname

```
  #!/bin/bash
 echo "what is your name?"
 read name
 if test "$name" = "Daryl"
     then
     echo "Hey, how are you?"
 else
      echo "sorry, im looking for Daryl"
 fi
```

Script for yourGrade

```
  #!/bin/bash

 ./yourname
 if[ 0 -eq "$?" ]
      then
      exit 0
 else
 echo "what is your grade?"

      read grade
      if [ "$grade" -gt 90 ]
      then 
      echo "Awesome! You got an A"

           elif [ "$grade -le 90 ] && [ "$grade" -gt 80 ]
           then
           echo "Good! You got a B"

               elif [ "$grade" -lt 80 ];
               then 
          echo "You need to work harder!"

 fi
```

I'm trying to get it so that in the script yourGrade it takes your name checks that it is Daryl, if not stops the program. Then if it is asks the grade, then reads the grade value and returns the appropriate message according to the grade.

Every time I run it I get...

```
 root@kali:~# . yourGrade
 What is your name?
 >Daryl
 Hey how are you!
 -bash : yourGrade: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token 'elif'
 -bash : yourGrade: line 17:'        elif [ "$grade" -le 90 ] && [ "$grade" -gt 80 ]'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm a newbie at this so this really helped!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got several problems.

The 'unexpected EOF' problem occurs because you have an unmatched double quote:

```
elif [ "$grade -le 90 ] && [ "$grade" -gt 80 ]
```

You need:

```
elif [ "$grade" -le 90 ] && [ "$grade" -gt 80 ]
```

Once you've fixed that, you've got a problem with:

```
if[ 0 -eq "$?" ]
```

The `[` is a command, and is only recognized as a command when it is a word on its own.  You need to have a space between the `if` and the `[`.

```
if [ 0 -eq "$?" ]
```

Then you'll have a problem because of your erratic indentation and in fact you have two `if` statements (one nested inside the other) and only one `fi`; fie upon you!

And finally note that those who score exactly 80 don't get told a thing about their grading.

```
#!/bin/bash

./yourname
if [ 0 -eq "$?" ]
then
    exit 0
else
    echo "what is your grade?"

    read grade
    if [ "$grade" -gt 90 ]
    then 
        echo "Awesome! You got an A"
    elif [ "$grade" -le 90 ] && [ "$grade" -gt 80 ]
    then
        echo "Good! You got a B"
    elif [ "$grade" -lt 80 ];
    then 
        echo "You need to work harder!"
    else
        echo "You scored 80; that's only barely acceptable"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: "Fie upon you"?  <groan>